# Form altering and ajax registration module

Tags: ajax, forms

I've altered forms in template.php and everything is displaying like I wanted, but when form is validating in my popup and some inputs are not filled, It shows error messages and default form template.

My code:

```
function default_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form['#id'] == 'user-register-form') {
    $form['account']['pass']['#type'] = 'password';
    $form['account']['pass']['#title'] = NULL;
    $form['account']['pass']['#attributes']['size'] = 60;
    $form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = 'Zarejestruj się';
    $form['account']['mail']['#description'] = t('');
    $form['account']['name']['#description'] = t('');
    $form['account']['pass']['#description'] = t('');
    $form['user_name']['und'][0]['value']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('Imię');
    $form['user_lastname']['und'][0]['value']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('Nazwisko');
    $form['user_job']['und'][0]['value']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('Stanowisko');
    $form['user_company']['und'][0]['value']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('Nazwa firmy');
    $form['account']['mail']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('E-mail');
    $form['account']['name']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('Nazwa użytkownika');
    $form['account']['pass']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('Hasło (min. 8 znaków)');
    $form['user_name']['und'][0]['value']['#title'] = NULL;
    $form['user_lastname']['und'][0]['value']['#title'] = NULL;
    $form['user_job']['und'][0]['value']['#title'] = NULL;
    $form['user_company']['und'][0]['value']['#title'] = NULL;
    $form['account']['mail']['#title'] = NULL;
    $form['account']['name']['#title'] = NULL;
    $form['account']['pass']['#title'] = NULL;
    $form['user_agreement']['und']['#title'] = NULL;
    $form['user_marketing1']['und']['#title'] = NULL;
    $form['user_marketing2']['und']['#title'] = NULL;
    $form['user_agreement']['und']['user_agreement_agree']['#title'] = NULL;
    $form['user_marketing1']['und']['user_marketing1_agree']['#title'] = NULL;
    $form['user_marketing2']['und']['user_marketing2_agree']['#title'] = NULL;
    $form['user_name']['und'][0]['value']['#weight'] = 0;
    $form['user_lastname']['und'][0]['value']['#weight'] = 1;
    $form['user_job']['und'][0]['value']['#weight'] = 2;
    $form['user_company']['und'][0]['value']['#weight'] = 3;
    $form['account']['mail']['#weight'] = 4;
    $form['account']['name']['#weight'] = 5;
    $form['account']['pass']['#weight'] = 6;
    $form['user_agreement']['und']['#weight'] = 7;
    $form['user_marketing1']['und']['#weight'] = 8;
    $form['user_marketing2']['und']['#weight'] = 9;
        $form['actions']['#weight'] = 10;
  }
}
```

EDIT:
I noticed the form is changing ID to user-register-form--2, user-register-form--3 etc. everytime form is not filled + messages are not printing...

Comment: make sure to set wrapper in '#ajax' section to some <form> parent